# MySQL - Student grade list, replace small grade by bonus grade

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT TestID, Grade FROM tests_points;
```

Returns:

```
+--------+-------+
| TestID | Grade |
+--------+-------+
|     10 |   125 |
|     11 |   110 |
|     12 |   100 |
|     13 |    75 |
|     14 |    50 |
|     15 |    65 |
|     16 |    70 |
|     17 |   100 |
|     18 |   100 |
+--------+-------+
```

But, tests ID 17 and 18 are "bonus tests", so I need replace the two lower grades by these two ones, and return the SUM of all grades.

So, how I can "replace"the two lower grades (From TestID 14 and 15) by testID 17 and 18 grades.

The "correct grade list" would be:

```
+--------+-------+
| TestID | Grade |
+--------+-------+
|     10 |   125 |
|     11 |   110 |
|     12 |   100 |
|     13 |    75 |
|     14 |    100|
|     15 |    100|
|     16 |    70 |
+--------+-------+
```

In the end I just need the SUM of all grades, fixing the lower grades.
SELECT SUM(Grade) FROM tests_points;

How can I do that?

Comment: i don't have access to mysql at the moment.. but you could try something like.. 
    `select testid, grade from tests_points where testid < 17 order by grade asc, top 2 `
should give you the lowest 2 grades.. so.. update them with the bonus test scores shoud work..

Comment: I could do that easily using php later to process the grades, but I would like to do it by using just MySQL ...

Comment: where do you want to put the sum of all grades?

Comment: I'll just show the sum of all grades for a specific student ... Something like: SUM of all of your grades: 680. This "680" it's the SUM of all grades, replacing the two lower grades by the bonus grades ...

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: Not exactly, I don't stud at any college, so ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need!

```
select testID, GREATEST(

  IF(
    grade = (select min(grade) from test_points),(select grade from test_points where testID = 17),
     grade)
  ,
    IF(grade = (select min(grade) from test_points WHERE grade > ( SELECT min(grade) FROM test_points))
     ,(select grade from test_points where testID = 18),
     grade)) as Score

from test_points 
where testID not in(17, 18)
```

[Demo on SQLfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44a3d6/13)

Comment: It was working when I was running in local machine, but testing on a server, it says: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now, there's something related with mysql version?

Comment: Oh, have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Answer (score 0):

the following query will get probably get what you want..

```
SELECT ttal-garba FROM 
(SELECT sum(c.grade) as garba FROM (SELECT * from tests_points  where testid < 17 order by grade asc limit 2) as c) as a,
(SELECT sum(grade) as ttal FROM tests_points) as b
```

(I know.. hard coding everything is bad ..)

Comment: Not exactly what I was expecting in results, apparently, it's just ignoring other grades and adding the bonus grades, but in some cases, bonus grades are not higher than normal grade, but thanks...

Comment: @AndréSteinn so.. what is the difference in just adding all the grades and ditching the lowest 2 grades?

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to add up all the values except the bottom two you can do something lik,e this.

First add a new field lets say test_type:

UPDATE test_points
   SET test_type = 'test';

Now we can just select using group by the sum. For example

```
SELECT test_type, (SUM(Grade) OVER (ORDER BY Grade DESC))
FROM test_Points
LIMIT 7;
```

This will return the sum of all values, but it will show 7 columns. If you want only the total, Throw a group by into the mix, and it will narrow it down to one field, or just select the 7th row number.